# How do I use typing in RxPy?

Tags: python, types, system.reactive, reactive, typing

I am not quite sure how I use typing in RxPy. I am currently doing this and this quite works:

```
b: rx.typing.Subject[int, int] = Subject()
b.pipe(
    ops.map(lambda a: a + 1)
)
b.on_next(1)
```

The IDE (PyCharm) warns me, if `on_next` gets an input that has the wrong value type. But my IDE wrongly says that my Subject has no `pipe` method. It seems that the IDE doesn't know, that Subject is also an Observable. Do I have to explicitly declare that the Subject is a mixing of multiple types?